# Usefulness of $\frac{ac}{b}<a-b+c$

Tags: inequality, applications

For $$a<b<0<c$$

I have a proof that shows that $$\frac{ac}{b}>a-b+c$$ But if $$a<0<b<c$$ Then $$\frac{ac}{b}<a-b+c$$

What I was wondering is how useful are these inequalities in these forms? Do they have any applications?

Comment: where have you found this inequality?

Comment: I made it up. What I'm concerned about is its applications.

Comment: $-2<-1<1$ but $\frac{-2\times 1}{-1}>-2-(-1)+1$

Comment: That is very true, let me look into it.

Comment: @Alessandro Ok the new condition is that if $$b<0$$ then the inequality sign is reversed

Comment: Isn't this just reordering $(a - b)(b - c) > 0$? Not sure that's going to be particularly useful.

Comment: @Derek It is but that wasn't how I derived it. So your saying it isn't useful in the aforementioned form?

Comment: No. I think they are just a bulk of problems to fill the precious time of the students and they have not a shred of value in science. Problems which today's world have faced to is much harder to be solved by these pieces of nonsense